# Select on multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two tables that contain completely separate information:

```
table: tires
columns:
Tire_id
name
model
etc 
etc

table: product
columns: 
product_id
name 
model 
etc
etc
```

I want to run a search on both tables at the same time, looking for keywords in the name and/or model

it should return products/tires from both databases, the ID's are not unique and might exist in both tables, being seperate products. Therefore on other parts of the site I have used a leading T or P to keep them seperate within the coding of the site.

I'm  struggling to get the search to work on both at the same time.

I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT * FROM product OR tire WHERE name = 'keyword' OR model = 'keyword'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a union:

```
select 'product' as type, product_id as id, name, model
from product
where ...
union all
select 'tire' as type, tire_id as id, name, model
from tire
where ...
```

Answer (score 0):

tyr this dude

```
SELECT p.*,t.fieldname FROM product as p,tire as t WHERE t.name = 'keyword' OR t.model = 'keyword' or p.name = 'keyword' OR p.model = 'keyword'
```